# Combining data from 2 Rails apps?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I have 2 Rails apps with the same models apart from a couple of attributes. I now need to merge these apps and I'm trying to work out how to merge their data. The challenges are:

- Conflicting ids. User from one app will have the same id as another user in the other app.
- Associated records. How do you keep associations when ids will need to change?
- Processing attributes that aren't identical. E.g. how do you make adjustments when one model is missing an attribute?

I'm aware of [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) and [yaml_db](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db) but I'm not sure they're a good solution for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar situation some time ago, with an app designed with database multitenancy. To merge all data into a single database I ended up creating a rake task, that would go through every record and association and recreate them in the new database.

The task had two arguments `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION`, and it would be run like: 
`rake db:merge SOURCE=some_database DESTINATION=new_database`. The task was run for each database I needed to merge.

Inside the rake task the idea was something like this:

```
namespace :db do
  task :merge => [:environment, :load_config] do |t, args|
  raise "Empty SOURCE provided" if not ENV["SOURCE"] or ENV["SOURCE"].empty?
  @source = ENV['SOURCE'].to_sym
  @destination = (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development').to_sym

  # for each model
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@source)
  # obtain the records and its associations
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@destination)
  # loop through each record and build all associated records
  # apply any necesary transformation to data
  # then build the record and fill it with the new associations
  # skip callbacks / validations if needed
  # then save
```

In some cases to keep track of ids in associations I used hashes, that tracked the original and 
new id.

I know the complexities of each app can make this process really hard, but in my
case this idea resulted to be very usefull as a starting point.

Comment: That seems reasonable enough 